# Is there a GNU Octave equivalent for the Matlab function "fit"?

Tags: matlab, octave, curve-fitting, data-fitting

My teacher in the signal analysis course has given me some Matlab code that I have to execute in order to complete a home assignment. I have always been using GNU Octave without troubles, but this time there is this command that is giving me headaches.

```
[c8,g8]=fit(time, sin_4_harmonic,’fourier8’)
```

I cannot find the function "fit" in GNU Octave, which is referenced for Matlab at the following url http://www.mathworks.se/help/curvefit/fit.html

Does anyone knows which package should I load, or if there is any equivalent?

Thanks =)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about math computation functions of a piece of software.

Comment: @AmirrezaKeshavarz this is not homework. He's asking what's the Octave equivalent to the Matlab function fit because he's trying to do his howework, which was designed for Matlab, in a different language.

Comment: @carandraug Thank you so much, this actually solved my problem :) Of course I would never ask people to solve my "homework", moreover it's not proper homework since I'm working my way towards a Master's degree. It is just that I strongly believe in open source software and the ideals behind it, hence my question.

Comment: @vcsjones I don't get why the question is off-topic. Could you please tell me how or where to formulate such a question in the correct way? stackoverflow.com is about programming, and asking information about a function of a scripting language seemed pertinent to me. I see you have a high rank and a lot of experience, hence I believe that I have just to learn from all that. Constructive criticism is always appreciated :)

Comment: @user2980080 Well, I am a human being and I can be just as wrong as anyone else. Since no one else agreed with me that it is off topic, perhaps I am wrong :-). Anyway, my original thinking was this was more about a tool (octave), not a programming language. However you're very right that there is a programming language behind it, so I redacted my close vote.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As far as I know, that function is not present in any of the Octave packages. However, the best place to look for something similar would be the [optim package](http://octave.sourceforge.net/optim/index.html), probably the function [nonlin_curvefit](http://octave.sourceforge.net/optim/function/nonlin_curvefit.html). Looking at the documentation, the model `fourier8` is of the type `Y = a0+a1*cos(x*p)+b1*sin(x*p)... +a8*cos(8*x*p)+b8*sin(8*x*p)`.

Answer (score 0):

A work-around may be using "polyfit" function. To get the values, use "polyval".

Comment: A more detailed example would be useful.

Comment: no. Academic work need fitting to other curves such as exp1, exp2 etc