# any Octave equivalent of fitdist?

Tags: matlab, octave

The Statistics package for Octave doesn't have the fitdist function in it yet. I have I code from Matlab that I want to run in Octave and relies heavily on this function. How could I replace this function in Octave?

Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19914430/4183191

Comment: perhaps you can use gaussian mixtures? https://octave.sourceforge.io/statistics/function/fitgmdist.html

Comment: I tried fitgmdist but the way it is implemented I couldn't get it to work. My data was X rows by 1 column, and it kept sending the error that it was 100 columns.